# How to properly represent permissions in use case diagram

Tags: use-case

If I have a user, that can let's say ... edit his profile.

A customer is a user that confirmed his email (just an example)

A customer has customer permissions and can view customer pages.

How do I represent this in a use case diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML use case diagrams offer the concept of generalization. That applies for both the use cases themselves, as well as the actors (see image):

[image: use case diagram with actor generalization]

If you need more detailed permissions, you write them down in your use case scenario – or a separate permission concept.